# Media query to override library

Tags: html, css, angular, media-queries, primeng

I have written media query to override library CSS but ins't working.
I am using primeng lib 14.0.2.

This is the code snippet:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .p-button {
    height: 2rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: add more details, replicate the issue in a stackblitz and share

Comment: I feel that you can simply by `@media(max-width: 600px) {...}`. see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). NOTE: be sure your .css is in styles.css. BTW, generally using media you use "mobile first": your .css code is for small screens and use media code for larger screens -in this case it's use min-width: 600px-

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the media queries only work if you have a viewport meta tag
in your html.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

There is an explanation here [Beginners Guide to Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries).  Read the section titled **The viewport meta tag**.  It says

> This is needed because by default, most mobile browsers lie about their viewport width.